# Внес путь в bashrc к файлу но файл все равно не запускается

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, wsl2

Работаю в Windows 10, уставновлен WSL

1. установил Python в C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
2. Создал папку C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\jupyter и запустил из под нее Bash
3. Добавил в .bashrc строки:

   `export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Users/Jack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"`
4. Перезапустил Bash,проверил что к PATH добавился путь:

   `env`

basch ответил:

`PATH=..:..:/mnt/c/Users/Jack/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310`

5. попытался запустить python.exe, а он не запускается, bash просто проглатывает ввод и печатает вновь пригласительную строку, т.е ошибку не выводит что файла не найден. Что я сделал не так???

Comment: ¿python.exe из-под linux? Вы бы лучше написали, зачем вообще заварили всю эту кашу.

Comment: Что выдаёт команда `which python.exe`? Я попробовал у себя - работает. Пайтон вызывается. PS. У вас очень подозрительный PATH. У меня в системе в PATH 57  папок.